# How to get Last Week of Month from Calendar in JAVA

Tags: java

How to get Last Week of Month from Calendar in JAVA

Comment: Do you mean the last full week? The week where the last day of the month falls? Only the part of that week that falls within the month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` to get the last day. Set the calendar day (of month) to that value and then get the day of week.  Working from that, you can figure out the start of the "last week", whatever that means to you (last Sunday?  last Monday?  last complete week?).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you meant correctly, something along the lines of this would probably do it:

```
public static int getLastWeekInMonth(int year, int month) {
    Calendar lastDayOfMonth = new GregorianCalendar();
    //Set the date to the day before the 1:st day of the next month
    lastDayOfMonth.set(year, month+1, 0);
    return lastDayOfMonth.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```